# Re-arranging tabs on product page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tabs, product-tab

I've added custom tabs to our Magento 2 store called "features","in the box" and "specification".

Currently the tabs on the site display in this order:

Details
Reviews
Warranty Info
Features
In the box
Specifications

We'd like to rearrange our tabs such that our custom ones come first, then the rest. We've tried everything we looked up so far with no success.

Comment: Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following by makeing changes in the phtml

```
app/design/frontend/Package/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templetes/product/view/details.phtml
```

If you rearrage the index of **$detailedInfoGroup**, it will be listed in that manner.
Below is my code of rearranging the tabs.This hint me be useful to you.

```
$detailedInfoGroup = array_reverse($detailedInfoGroup); 
unset($detailedInfoGroup[0]);
$detailedInfoGroup[] = "reviews.tab"; 
unset($detailedInfoGroup[1]);
```

Comment: Not sure what part of the details.phtml file the code above should go on. (top, bottom, after some block of code).

Comment: look for $detailedInfoGroup. Make changes before foreach loop of $detailedInfoGroup